# How to figure out if two sentences have the same meaning with AI?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow, nlp, similarity

I have two sentences which might be similar in meaning. 
Are there a useful and successful (machine learning) algorithms, which is able to determine the semantic similarity?

Are there any approaches which can handle this task and are easy to use?

An approach via Keras or Tensorflow as a Framework would work perfectly in my use case.

Thank you!

Comment: I changed the word syntactic to semantic; assuming that's what you meant. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 2):

This corresponds to an NLP task called [paraphrase detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraphrasing_(computational_linguistics)). It's an active area of research, as far as I know there's no ready-to-use system able to perform this task very well, but there are probably a good few methods and prototypes around. A quick search gives these links for example:

- https://aclweb.org/aclwiki/Paraphrase_Identification_(State_of_the_art)
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.02820

Comment: I'm new to AIML. Right now I'm working with a requirement where I need to see if two sentences are similar semantically. I'm searching for an API which compares given sentance with another array of sentences and provide us with matching one from passed array of sentances. The above comment by @Erwan in 2020 reads "no ready-to-use" state of system, so just want to know if there is any proven algo/API implementation published now. Please let me through this folks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @gubera You should [ask a new question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), this is an area which evolves very fast and there are new methods which can do this quite well nowadays (not perfectly of course).